# Como selecciono las Cards Views (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

En mi aplicación hay un recycler view relleno de cardViews con los datos de una consulta SQL, la cosa es que busco una interfaz para seleccionar una CardView y luego aplicar acciones que tendré en botones de la Action Bar, he estado buscando y a lo mejor podría utilizar la interfaz onSelectedItem() pero no he encontrado ningún ejemplo práctico, donde se utilicé para algo parecido.

¿Que interfaz puedo utilizar para seleccionar cardview, para luego aplicar diferentes acciones sobre ellos?

(Ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando)
[image: Ejemplo de propiedad que quiero]

Comment: Hola @RubénGonzálezGarcía, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: gracias por la bienvenida y la sugerencia.